How can I configure routes in a Vue.js application to handle query parameters?
What configurations are required in my routes to handle the query parameter userActivity for a URL like https://somesite.com/feedpool?userActivity=false?
I'm using Vite as a build tool, with the base URL set to feedpool. When I enter the query parameter without any route configuration, the page displays an error: "The server is configured with a public base URL of /feedpool/ - did you mean to visit /feedpool/feedpool?userActivity=false instead?"

what happens if you go to https://somesite.com/feedpool/?userActivity=false

From memory you cannot perform routing based on query params. But you can read them on any page using route.query

with the base URL set to feedpool clearly you've set it to /feedpool/ perhaps set it to /feedpool (but yeah, nothing to do with routing)
